# Unexpected ActionView::MissingTemplate errors on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an application, which is live for a couple of months. Recently I've been receiving a lot of `ActionView::MissingTemplate` errors, for both `Missing template` and `Missing partial`, but the thing is, they seem to happen more or less randomly.

The only way i found to reproduce the problem was furiously changing browser language via [Quick Language Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie?hl=en) plugin for Chrome. If i did it fast enough, eventually one of the requests returned 500. I use [http_accept_language](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language) gem to change the site's locale (in application_controller).

Other possible factors:

- **happens only in production environment**
- unfortunately it happens for "standard" users as well (not trying to abuse the service)
- it's not browser related (happens on all of them)
- it's not action related (happens on multiple actions)
- it's not language related (happens on multiple languages)

I'm not sure how to address this issue, it may be related to server strain, since we've gotten more traffic lately.

Any hint, idea or even direction would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Specs: `Rails 4.1.5`, `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

Backtrace: http://pastebin.com/nsaxPvAB

Example of error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template static_pages/privacy_policy, application/privacy_policy with {:locale=>[:ru, :en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "usr_path/releases/20160112094523/app/views" * "usr_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/dark_api-7386deedfd7b/app/views" * "usr_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/app/views" * "usr_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views" * "usr_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
```

Comment: It's very hard to try to answer this.  Can you add the stack trace for one of the times where it happens?  This should point you towards the page which is calling the missing template/partial which should give you some clues.

Comment: Added specs, backtrace and a full error message. The problem is, it happens on multiple pages and all of them work most of the time.

Comment: How are you deploying? I'm guessing Capybara given that you have a timestamp in the view path. I've seen similar issues where Unicorn doesn't pick up the changed file handles properly, and keeps looking for an old template that's been deleted (as Capybara only keeps _n_ previous releases). If you hard-restart the app server process and the errors go away, that's an indicator your problem could be something similar.